# Adding strings together in CUDA?

Tags: c++, cuda

What I want to do is have both strings processed in the device and called on the host. I get an error telling me that calling host function from global is not allowed. With that in mind, how would I go about re-structuring this code so that it is run through the device?

```
__global__ void whatever(string *x, string *y){
    *x += *y;}
int main(){
    string x, y, *x_in, *y_in;
    x = "Hello ";
    y = "World!\n";
    cudaMalloc((void**)&x_in, sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&y_in, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(x_in, &x, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(y_in, &y, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    whatever << <1, 1 >> > (x_in, y_in);
    cudaMemcpy(&x, x_in, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaMemcpy(&y, y_in, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaFree(&x_in);
    cudaFree(&y_in);
    cout << x;
    return 0; }
```

Comment: get rid of your use of `string` and do everything using C-style `char` arrays.  If you figure out how to do that using ordinary C or C++, the CUDA version will be a trivial modification.

Comment: This is outside of the scope of this question, but I wonder if, once OP makes this code work, performance-wise this approach will turn out being counter-productive. I just can't see string concatenation as a kind of task benefiting from being run on a GPU.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answer to your question: you call `*x += *y;`, i. e. concatenation and assignment operation for `std::string` objects (obviously defined only as a host function in STL).

About restructuring - you can pass to device `char*` buffers (of course, allocated on the device) instead of string objects and work with them.

Some more points about the code:

- You copy only `sizeof(int)` bytes from/to device, why? I see that your data is more than 4 bytes;
- You allocate only `sizeof(int)` bytes for each object, why?
- You use `<< <1, 1> >>` syntax instead of `<<<1, 1,>>>` (I believe that it's only formatting issue after copy-pasting code here);
- And the main question - possibly you describe what do you want to achieve by this piece of code?

Comment: Bullet 3 is due to code editor being unaware of CUDA-specific syntax. It does not affect anything functionally. In the same vein, the smart editor would replace `a+b` with `a + b`, etc.